# Not able to click on specific print button in IE using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web, internet-explorer, printing

I am trying to click on a print button on a specific web page, but cannot figure out the correct VBA code.

This is the print portion of my code:

```
With IE
    .Document.querySelector("[data-testid='moreActionsButton']").Click
    .Document.querySelector("[data-testid='createPdfButton']").Click
    .Document.querySelector("[data-testid='detailed-button']").Click
    .Document.querySelector("[data-testid='download-pdf-button']").Click
End With
```

This is the code on the web page for the button I am trying to click:

```html
<div class="PdfForm__ButtonBar-sc-1h3mt9w-0 bjYOJP">
<button class="Button-sc-19jm674-2 kWKZnE" 
   data-testid="createPdfButton" variant="success" 
    type="submit">Download PDF</button>
</div>
```

Please note the the print options are in a pop-up so submit does not work.  I also tried doing another query selector by as you can see the testid is the same as another step.  Everything works up to this point.

Comment: Your example is not giving much idea. We need to know how the process works manually then we can get the idea of how it should be automated. You said you are not able to click the print button but sample code shows that it is a submit button to download a pdf file. I suggest please try to provide detailed information that may help us to understand the issue properly.

Comment: The manual process is to select the save options and the button saves/prints a pdf of a report when clicked on.  While it says Submit, using a submit command resubmits the URL even when I try to focus on the popup containing the button.

Comment: Do you mean after clicking on saves/print button IE browser displays the Save open file popup at the bottom, of the screen? If yes, then you should try to use some third party libraries to click the desired option on that popup. You will not be able to click it just using VBA. Let me know if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: On the webpage.  It starts with a save/print button.  You click that and a pop-up appears where you must select options for how you want the report to look (summary vs. detail).  After you select the options you need to click a final save/print button which has the above code.  The first save/print button and the last save/print button are different buttons, but have the same code.

Comment: Here I want to confirm with you whether you are getting this prompt when you manually perform the operation? [See here](https://imgur.com/a/uLezJMb). If yes, as I said you need third party library to automate this OS based download prompt.

Comment: No.  That is the step after what I am attempting to do.

Comment: The code posted in the original post is not enough for producing the issue also description in the comments not giving much idea. For more clarification, I suggest trying to provide the code example that we can try to use to reproduce the issue. We can test it and try to provide you further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.